# error "EntityMalformedException" when creating a node as guest

Tags: nodes, entities, users, debugging

We have a node type with permission to create new nodes for guests. When we try to create a new node of this type as guest we get the following error:

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7844 of /var/www/miwula/includes/common.inc).

In watchdog I get only the same message and nothing in apache's log.

I created a new node type with no other fields and with create permissions for guests too. Same problem.

I have no idea what I can do.

Comment: Was it working? Like, ever? If yes, what have you changed? If no, just delete it and recreate.

Comment: it was the first try. as logged in user, no matter which role, it works. we already migrated 16.000 nodes of that type, so I'm not able to delete this node type. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Why did you do that?! Proper order is: first, test environment; second, migrate content.

Comment: you're right. but first until today we know that the guest should be able to edit this node type.

Comment: I created a new node type with no other fields and with create permissions for guests too. Same problem.

Comment: Ok, that tells something. Now please edit this directly into your question - comments usually are not read by majority. Also, which version of Drupal are you using, exactly?

Comment: currently using 7.38

Comment: The "bundle" property is node type.  Having that file reported as the error source tells us nothing, because everything runs through that file.  A more helpful piece of information would be a backtrace of the error.  Can you copy your site to a development space, enable the devel module, and get a backtrace?  [Howto generate backtrace](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32233/how-to-generate-a-stack-trace-from-drupal-upon-errors)

Comment: You say "We have a node type with permission to create new nodes for guests". How you do it.