# Site crashed: Ajax error

Tags: debugging

I have been looking for a solution on the internet before asking for your help here.

My drupal site was working fine since yesterday when I create a calendar event chain ( this is a custom module) and i clicked "save", then this error appeared:

[image]

I have checked from the recent log message and found this

[image]

I dont know what have happened since I cleared all the queuing using queue manager. The funny thing is that if I use the backup database, which had backed up before this error happened from the production site to my localhost, then everything works fine and I am able to create the even and save it. So is there any problem with the database ? I wish i could use the backup database on my production site ? :/

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: looks like a problem with your custom entity. to find the error, trace it, see here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32233/how-to-generate-a-stack-trace-from-drupal-upon-errors or use https://www.drupal.org/project/past

Comment: Thank you very much. Following those links above. I am able to find a solution for this error: 'drush sqlq 'update system set schema_version=7100 where name="redirect"'
drush updb -y'. Source [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2578019)